# Having issue with InputStream

Tags: java, android, stream

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {


        // When an file is picked
        if (requestCode == 3 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked any file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("EXCEPTION_ERROR",e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I tried it. I added more source code. But, `inputStream` is giving error.

> EXCEPTION_ERROR: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
>
> System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
>
> System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:151)

Uri :

> content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3356
>
> content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3331

Comment: What is the value of uri? Perhaps you should log it so that you can see it.

Comment: I don't know android, but is content a real content-type like file and http?

Comment: @NomadMaker There's difference between `uri` and `url`

Comment: Yes I know. I'm sorry, but the spell-checker on this frigging phone got me. But is content an acceptable scheme for a uri?

Comment: Are you using that code directly in onActivityResult? If not then try there.

Comment: @blackapps Yes! I am using there.

Comment: @blackapps Look I am using that there.

Comment: That should work.

Comment: Try to open that file in a different app.

Comment: @blackapps Sorry! I couldn't get you. Did you mean I have to create another application and do the same?

Comment: No. Just take the Files app or another file manager app. Go to the same file and try to let it open.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies on the uris. Usually if a uri starts with `content://`, that means that uri suppose to be included in an intent and to be send to other apps. And up the other apps how parse that uri.
So you could try one of the folllowing and hopefully it works.

Change from this

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3356
```

to this

```
file://document/3356 //An absolute path for "document/3356" is better like "/storage/emulated/0/document/3356".
```

Or, from this

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3356
```

to this

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.file/document/3356
```

You can use `Uri.parse()` to get an instance of uri.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://document/3356");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/document/3356");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.providers.downloads.file/document/3356");
```